# How to display score of Hibernate Search query results

Tags: hibernate-search

Hibernate Search allows to sort search results on relevance. Is it possible to obtain and display (e.g. in a jsp view) this information using Lucene query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Query in Hibernate Search can return Projections rather than the simple list of matching entities.
A projection result essentially means each result is an array containing the sequence of projections you asked for. Normally this is used to extract text from a specific field, so to not need loading the data from the database, but there are Projection constants to return also the *Score* value or the *Explanation* of the scoring.

```
query.setProjection( ProjectionConstants.SCORE, ProjectionConstants.EXPLANATION, ProjectionConstants.THIS );
```

See also the [Reference documentation on projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections) explaining this and more.